# Replacement Spring - Spring Too Compressed Under Load

Tags: suspension, vauxhall

Yesterday I helped a friend replace his springs on his Vauxhall Corsa C 1.2 Life (2004). The fronts went well however there's a bit of a bizarre issue on the rears. The rear of a Corsa uses a trailing arm setup, not a typical coilover system. Replacement spring is a 30mm lowering spring from Direnza.

As you can see from the photo (which was taken with the wheels on the ground), two of the coils are very close together (pretty much touching) - this doesn't look right?

On a short test drive, there was a banging noise from most bumps. The same noise was there prior to fitting these springs, however the noise was only occasional (we've spent quite a while prior to the spring fitting trying to diagnose the noise with no success. The noise is coming from the rear of the car.
I guess there are two questions here:

Should the spring look the way it does in the photo, and why might replacing the springs made the noise more apparent (perhaps it's lower/stiffer maybe?).

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Both springs look the same? I'd send the picture to Direnza and have them tell you if that's the way the spring should look. I put Eibach lowering springs on a car before. They ended up being too soft and the suspension would bottom off of the snubber. I ended up putting a set of airbags which fit inside of the springs as supports. I *liked* the ride height, but it hammered on the suspension over bumps. My experience with what you've shown here is they should not be touching, but my experience is limited in this area.